# Cannot populate adapter in CoroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I'm learning coroutines and tried to do small experiment. I wanted to get data from backend and populate them using recyclerview.

So, to do that:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout....)

    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerview.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    GlobalScope.launch {

        val dataList = Repository().getData() //

        runOnUiThread {
            adapter = Adapter(dataList, ..., listener)
            bodyPart.adapter = adapter 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}

suspend fun getData(): List<data> = coroutineScope {
    return@coroutineScope if (...) {
        getFromApi()
    } else {
        getLocal()
    }
}
```

But this does not work at all. Adapter function like `onCreateViewHolder` does not get called. Whenever I move the part of setting adapter data outside the `GlobalScope.launch` it works fine. I do not understand why is this happening and how should I tackle this problem. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just to educate not really to answer the question. Don't use `GlobalScope`. Specify your own scope.

Comment: try change runOnUiThread with

withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ }

Comment: @RofieSagara No, that does not work :/

Comment: Are you setting the recyclerview adapter somwhere else? In your code you're setting the adapter for bodyPart.

Comment: Did you find an answer?